# when_pressed and when_released functions in gpiozero not working

Tags: python-3, gpiozero

I have the following code, and I cannot figure out how to make `when_pressed` and `when_released` work. The callback functions just do not run to the press and release.

On the other hand, properties such as `is_pressed` do work as expected.

```
MyDoor(object):

    ...

    def function1(self, gpio_button, held_duration):

        ds = DoorSound()

        gpio_button.when_pressed = ds.start_door_sound
        # gpio_button.when_pressed = lambda: ds.start_door_sound() # <-- I have also tried this alternative
        gpio_button.when_released = ds.stop_door_sound
        # gpio_button.when_released = lambda: ds.stop_door_sound()

        do_loop = True
        while do_loop:
            ...
            # do more stuff and at some point set do_loop to False

    ...
```

`DoorSound` is defined as follows:

```
class DoorSound(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file_path = 'sounds/door_sound.mp3'
        self.pygame_door = pygame.mixer


    def start_door_sound(self):
        print('Start door sound!')
        self.pygame_door.init()
        self.pygame_door.music.load('sounds/door_sound.mp3')
        self.pygame_door.music.play()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    def stop_door_sound(self):
        print('Stop door sound!')
        self.pygame_door.music.stop()
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

I also tried:

- `start_door_sound` and `stop_door_sound` functions inside the `MyDoor` class
- the following simple function, that when it is called directly, instead of as a callback, works. And not trying to stop it.

.

```
def door_sound(self):

    """Reproduce a DOOR SOUND"""

    print('♩ ♪ ♫ ♬  Door sound ♩ ♪ ♫ ♬')
    print()

    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds/door_sound.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        continue
```

but none of them made any difference.

The text inside the functions is never printed, so I guess the problem is that somehow the callback function is never called.

I read somewhere that `when_pressed` and `when_released` functions might not work well inside loops, but unfortunately, the documentation is not very extensive so I don't know if that might be the case.
In any case, `function1` runs inside some `while` loops.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: I'd try and minimise this as much as possible. It doesn't look like you need any of those classes. Also try removing the `sleep` as that might interfere. And it won't actually make a difference being there at the end.

Comment: An alternative approach could be to switch to a loop that waits for the button to be pressed using `btn.wait_for_press()` instead of using callbacks.

Comment: @ben_nuttall, thanks for the tips. I will give it a try. Regarding the `wait_for_press` function, would that make the music play as long as the button is pressed and stop it as soon as the button is released or when a timeout is reached?

Comment: By removing `sleep` it seems to be working most of the time. However, I made sure I removed all of them from my code and sometimes it randomly does not work...